# how to compare performance of x11 forward vs vnc

Tags: networking, xorg, remote-desktop, vnc

tl;dr:  How do I measure cpu/memory usage, bandwidth usage, "laggyness" of x11 forward vs vnc?

My workstations + laptops all run on xubuntu 20.04, and I just realized belatedly that a piece of software I need has some unknown 16.04 dependency.  That will take a while to sort out; in the meantime, I can remote login to another box running 16.04 and run the software using x11 forward or vnc.  All the machines are on a local network and security is not a concern here.

I thought that x11 forwarding is less resource intensive (no need to fire up a desktop, only has to handle graphics of the program), so I expected that the program would run more smoothly under x11 forwarding than with vnc.  But when I tried it both way they seem to be able the same, which surprised me.  If anything it seems to run a tiny bit more smoothly/stable under vnc, but it's surjective.

Question:  Is there a way to objectively measure/quantify the CPU/ram usage, bandwidth usage, and "laggyness", of running this piece of software using x11 forwarding vs vnc?

Many thanks!

Comment: Got here after thinking about kind same. About the network trafic we may use something as wireshark.